# complement of \ with regular expression

Tags: regex

I am testing my regular expression and I am getting a bit confused

from my understanding

`[]` is used to indicate a set of characters
`^` is the complement. So [^a] would be a set of any characters excluding `a`

I am having trouble with this particular bit of regular expression

`[^\]` This excludes the character set `\`

I tried testing this on an online regular expression tester with the string `a\d\c\e\d` but no results would display. I feel that I might be missing something but I am not sure what that could be.

Comment: I think you mean "complement".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backslash is the escape character in regular expressions. To refer to it literally, you have to escape it:

```
[^\\]
```